# Move a rigidbody to its facing direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a rigidbody2D which is rotating when the user press the left arrow, I want when the user press the up arrow to move that object to each facing direction. Any help?

[image]

```
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            rigidbody2D.AddTorque(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
        }
        else
        {
            rigidbody2D.angularVelocity = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get forward direction of an GameObject using, `transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);` 
this returns the vector with the object's forward direction, you can then use this vector to translate the object using 
`transform.Translate(<vector here>);` or `transform.Translate(transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward));` . If you have a character controller attached to this object then you can use that component to move the character as well.

Comment: What if I use rigidbody for a movement like `rb.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(rb.velocity, targetVelocity, smoothTime * Time.fixedDeltaTime);`